# How to pass a float * array as a property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, properties, key-value-coding

I recently changed the type of one of my properties from `@property (readonly) NSImage *someData` to `@property (readonly) float *someData`. The data is a large array of floats. Before the change, the `NSImage` was created from that float data.

Since then, whenever I called `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"someData"]` in my code, I received the following error:

> `[MyController 0x109161710> valueForUndefinedKey:]:`
>   `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key someData.`

All other properties continued to work just fine. Now one solution to this is the following piece of code:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"someData"]) {
        return someData; // throws a warning because (float*) is not id
    } else {
        return [super valueForUndefinedKey:key];
    }
}
```

This works for now, but throws a warning about an `incompatible pointer type returning 'float *' from a function with result type 'id'`. So it can not be a final solution.

So the way I understand this is that you can not have a property of pointer type. Is that correct?
Also, I really want to pass that pointer through a property. Is there some way to wrap a pointer in some data structure that would make this work?

**Edit:** The float array can be a few 100 Mb in size, so I don't want to copy it around if I can help it. I suppose copying it into an NSArray would help, but that would definitely be bad for performance.

Comment: @beryllium: I am passing an array of floats.

Comment: oh, in this case see @AnthonyBlake answer. I can suggest to make NSArray with NSNumbers.

Comment: @beryllium: I updated the question accordingly. I believe that an NSArray (and NSNumbers for the matter) would copy my source data. The source data is necessarily a float array though and I don't want to copy that data around because it can  be huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @BastiBechtold's comment below: Using an NSValue to point to the array is the best way to encapsulate the array of floats in an NSObject without copying it.

Comment: I have to read and write the raw float data. Also, the data can get quite big (a few 100 Mb), so I don't want to copy it around if I can help it. Because of that, I am wary of wrapping it in an NSArray.

Comment: @Basti See the edited answer about creating your own NSObject that contains a pointer to the array of floats.

Comment: I suppose an NSObject would work. `[NSValue valueWithPointer:someData]` works even better though.

Comment: Ahh yes -- NSValue is obviously the right way to do it. I'm new to Objective-C -- good to know about NSValue, thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a property of type `float*`. You even can `synthesize` its accessors.

You can't use [key-value coding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) on it.